# Icon fonts are not working in Opera Mobile

Tags: css, icons, font-face, webfonts

I started using the FontAwesome collection and test it on different OS / browsers.
I found out that it works with IE > 7, Firefox, Chrome, Safari (iPhone, iPad), Opera Desktop, that's really nice!

Only Opera Mini do not support **@font-face**, but Opera Mobile (v 12.19) does.
BUT it only works with *normal* fonts with alphabetical  letters.
Iconic fonts like [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome) or [icnfnt](http://www.icnfnt.com/#/) don't work!

I think the reason is, because the icons don't use normal alphabetical characters. The icon characters are described in hexadecimal format, (ISO CSS content: `i:before {content: "\f000"}`). I try to describe the icons in the numeric format in the HTML code (convert from hex into decimal: `<i>&#61440;</i>`) but this also doesn't work.

So is there a solution to display iconic fonts on Opera Mobile?

related link: [HTML Glyphs](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/)

[image]

Comment: the presto engine by opera should support icon fonts, if you can provide a jsfiddle of how you implement them, maybe I can suggest a more compatible way.

Comment: EDIT: examples and implementation showed on this site: http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#integration

Comment: I don't have opera mobile and you can look at icomoon.io for some good icon fonts and try another resource...additionally, you may not be supplying the right icon font file for opera to use, you may need to try EOT, TTF, SVG files to see if it renders any of those.

Comment: @timaschew - If you look at the font awesome homepage on Opera Mini does it display the fonts correctly?

Comment: @IlanBiala trust me, there is no problem about the wrong font file. It works with normal alphabetical fonts. I found out the icons on icomoon.io works fine! So it'S seems to be related to the font file. @BillyMoat Opera Mini doesn't work in any case, because of the not supportet `@font-face`! My question is only about Opera Mobile, not Opera Mini.

Comment: @timaschew you won't have to worry about problems with opera in a few months anyway, they are switching to webkit and will support everything chrome and safari do.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues with Opera Mobile/Opera Mini. What worked for me was switching from Font Awesome to [Elusive Icons](http://aristeides.com/elusive-iconfont/index.html). They are also "built for Bootstrap" and have basically the same icons available, i didn't even have to change any of the icon class names when i switched, only the font files and less/css files.

Answer (score 0):

> I found out that it works with IE > 7...

Font-Awesome comes with an IE7 stylesheet which *doesn't* use `@font-face`. Have you tried including this to see if it also fixes the Opera Mobile issue?

`font-awesome-ie7.min.css`

Comment: I already try what you say... this is really crappy... I'm on Android 4.2.1 (Nexus 4) Whats your OS version / device?

Comment: Oh god, sorry, just realised I was checking in the default browser and not Opera! Tried in Opera and no, it doesn't work. I imagine a fix would still be to include the IE7 stylesheet when the browser identifies as Opera Mobile (I think you can use Modernizr to detect that).

Comment: I force to load the IE7 css every time. I'm very sure, the Opera Mobile problem has nothing to do with the IE7 hack

Comment: Well the IE7 stylesheet doesn't rely on `@font-face`. Are you loading the IE7 stylesheet *after* the regular one?

Comment: Sure, I load it after the default css

Comment: I think the best bet is to probably raise the issue on Font Awesome's githup page https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues and with Opera too. http://www.opera.com/support/bugs/ I wouldn't know how to debug websites on Opera Mobile, so can't really offer much help!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly  you can use adobe edge inspect and inspect using chrome dev tools plugin that adobe provides and inspect with the chrome tools as you would a regular website. Hopefully that helps a little. :)

Comment: The IE7 css only addresses the :before pseudo-element which isn't supported by IE7 but is supported by Opera. My guess is that it's related to the unicode mapping if font embeds with normal letters are working. Try adding a font that maps to the letter A and see if it works. Most font icons use PUA mapping for font icons so they don't interfere with accessibility.